# How to project plane with image to another model

Tags: uv

I imported a plane and a openstreetmap model to coordinates and want the image of the plane projected to the osm model.

I know it can be done with simple uvmapping by hand but it is hard to align the image with te osm model. I think it is possible to project the image from the plane to the osm model, does somebody know how?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DataTransfer modifier to transfer the UVs of the plane to your meshes.

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Comment: Thanks! it works like a charm, it did raise another question but I asked a new question for that.

Comment: @Robin Betts: Thanks to the answer from MACHIN3 I stumbled on a similar question asked on stackexchange: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51492/how-to-project-uvs-from-one-object-to-another