# Exclude sides when using the DataTransfer modifier

Tags: uv

How can the side faces be excluded when using the datatransfer modifier?
[image]

This is an addinitonal question following my previous question:
[enter link description here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109079/how-to-project-plane-with-image-to-another-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose appropriate name of UV layers in Data Transfer modifier settings, but for sides you can assign another material with different UVmap.

[image]

[image]